# How to determine if a Windows 10 Store App is Minimized (Iconic)

Tags: c#, dllimport, windows-10-universal

My desktop app needs to consistently determine the windows state (*restored* vs. *minimized*) of UWP apps running on a PC with x64 Win10.   When only 1 app is running, a call to native method  **IsIconic**(IntPtr hWnd) works on the *ProcessName* “ApplicationFrameHost”  associated with the *MainWindowTitle* of the UWP app.  However, if there are 2 UWP apps running, only the one first opened can be determined.

To demonstrate, my sample code below outputs the following for 3 sample cases using the Windows 10 Weather and Calculator apps.

> A. Case of only 1 UWP app running (It is minimized)

```
Weather has 2 processes
Weather process name: ApplicationFrameHost
Weather is minimized: True
```

> B. Case of Calculator opened 1st, Weather 2nd (Both are actually minimized)

```
Calculator has 2 processes
Calculator process name: ApplicationFrameHost
Calculator is minimized: True
Weather has 1 processes
Weather process name: Microsoft.Msn.Weather
Weather is minimized: False
```

> C. Case of Weather opened 1st, Calculator 2nd (Both are actually minimized)

```
Calculator has 1 processes
Calculator process name: Calculator
Calculator is minimized: False
Weather has 2 processes
Weather process name: ApplicationFrameHost
Weather is minimized: True
```

In summary, A. works, B. only detects Calculator properly, and C. only detects Weather properly.

This method loops through the processes that have a window name of Calclulator or Weather, and exits as true if the IsIconic method is true.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var result = IsWindowMinimizedIconic("Calculator");
    Debug.WriteLine("Calculator is minimized: " + result.ToString());

    result = IsWindowMinimizedIconic("Weather");
    Debug.WriteLine("Weather is minimized: " + result.ToString());
}

public static bool IsWindowMinimizedIconic(string windowTitle)
{
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.MainWindowTitle.StartsWith(windowTitle)).ToArray();
    Debug.WriteLine("{0} has {1} processes", windowTitle, processes.Length);

    foreach (Process process in processes)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("{0} process name: {1}", windowTitle, process.ProcessName); 
        if (IsImmersiveProcess(process.Handle)) //TEST WINDOWS STORE APPS
        {
            // see if minimized/iconic
            if (IsIconic(process.MainWindowHandle))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/// <summary>
/// Determines if the specified window is minimized (iconic).
/// </summary>
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);

/// <summary>
/// Determines if the specified window is UWP.
/// </summary>
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool IsImmersiveProcess(IntPtr hWnd);
```

It seems the key to this is understanding the *ApplicationFrameHost* and how it associates with the real application process. How can I get the window state consistently?